# Complexity of the recurrence T(n)=T(n−2)+1/lgn?

Tags: algorithm, math

This is a problem from the CLRS book.
The Introduction to Algorithms Study Group website gave the following answer to it:
[image]

(http://clrs.skanev.com/04/problems/03.html)

Is this answer right? I don't understand the last two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. Also there's a typo, instead of infinity there should be n. For strict mathematical proof you should ask on another stackExchange site (mathematical one). But for your intuition I can show the following.

Let's imagine that `n = 2^2^k` then `sum of 1/lg(i)` equals

```
1/lg2 + 1/lg3 + 1/lg4 + 1/lg5 + 1/lg6 + 1/lg7 + 1/lg8 + 1/lg9 +
1/lg10 + 1/lg11 + 1/lg12 + 1/lg13 + 1/lg14 + 1/lg15 + ... + 1/lg n-1
```

and this is approximately

```
1/lg2 + 1/lg2 + 1/lg4 + 1/lg4 + 1/lg4 + 1/lg4 + 1/lg8 + 1/lg8 +
1/lg8 + 1/lg8 + 1/lg8 + 1/lg8 + 1/lg8 + 1/lg8 + ... + 1/lg n-1
```

equals

```
1/1 + 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/3 +
1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 + ... + 1/ (2^k - 1) (as lg n = 2^k)
```

After combining we have

```
sum(1/i * 2^i) from 1 to 2^k-1
```

where the last member is `n/2 / 2^k-1` which is something about `2^(2^k-k-1)` and this is far not theta of `lg lg n = k`. And of course the whole sum is even bigger.

Comment: Approximating the sum by an integral, you indeed expect a behavior like `Li(n) ~ n/ln(n)`.

Comment: And this is far away from lg lg n